# permission denied error while trying to run .sh file

Tags: permissions

I am getting the following permission denied error while trying to run .sh file on lubuntu:

```
./file.sh: 11: ./file.sh: ./qemu-system-i386: Permission denied
```

note: chmod +x file.sh , command is already given.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it's because you're on a 64-bit system and the 32-bit libraries aren't on your system. Are you on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: it's an 32 bit system.

Answer (score 1):

use `sudo` to execute `file.sh`

```
 sudo ./file.sh
```

any user can execute command `qemu-system-i386` but seems like device that you want to use is either owned by root or read-only.
if you want to use device in read-only mode then you have to add `readonly=on` attribute. i don't know what you have written in `file.sh`. so i am giving some reference that may help you.

- [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=770740#51) is long discussion about similar problem
- [here](http://www.ocp.inf.ethz.ch/wiki/Documentation/Installation#toc23) is some information that may be helpful
- [qemu-system-i386](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/qemu-system-i386/): use documentation  more info about
  `qemu-system-i386`

Comment: But the execute permission is on for "world", so anyone should be able to execute yours.

Comment: i have changed  answer .

Comment: I am having the exacly the same error when using `sudo ./file.sh` the file I am trying to execute is a linux virtual machine program could be found at  [levinux.com] I am new to qemu, therefore thank you for the document.